# Broken disk size after incomplete dd operation

Tags: dd, disk

Once I was writing an ISO image into my USB disk using `dd`, I mistakenly pulled it out, and now it has only 10 MB of size. The correct size is 32 GB.

Note that this smaller size is for the whole USB disk (`/dev/sdc`), not for one partition inside it.

Is there any way to recover the size of this USB disk? I don't need any data recovery.

Comment: What would happen if you just again overwrite ISO on that USB disk?  Does it fail for insufficient disk size?

Comment: Are you sure `/dev/sdc` is smaller?  How are you measuring the size?  Does `blockdev --getsz /dev/sdc` match what you think the size is?

Comment: @yaegashi If I `dd` again, it claims insufficient disk size, and only copied 10 MB.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by manually delete `/dev/sdc` device file, which kept exist after the USB drive is unplugged. It seems the issue is caused by some kind of un-updated device metadata.